# Sequence generation for new ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where there are 2 tables A and B. There is a column named ID which is a primary key for A  and foreign key for table B where the tables have one to many relationship between them. In table A for ID column we have entries 1,2,3 and for them we have corresponding multiple entries for one ID and another column in table B named SEQ where a sequence has been created for entries in it. Now for entries for ID 1, I have 3 entries in table B with SEQ 1,2,3 but when new ID entry will be there then i need the sequence again to start from 1 for that ID.**Can you please help me to do that.

TABLE A

[image]

Comment: Please share at least what you have tried so far

Comment: I have created a sequence for SEQ column but it is generating on the basis of seq.nextval whenever new entries are coming. So for me sequences are getting created like 1,2,3,4,5,6..... But I want it in the form of the screenshot i have given above for table B.That for new id new sequence will be created

Comment: do you want to automatically update,delete,insert entries in table b regarding what happens in table a ? If so, for me I think you have a clear case where you can implement a trigger in table a to take care of table b

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you not to store the `SEQ` value. Why would you? It is easy to calculate it whenever needed. How? Like this, using `row_number` analytic function:

```
SQL> with b (id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'TRI'   from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'TRI'   from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'TRI'   from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'ROHIT' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'ROHIT' from dual union all
  7     select 3, 'RAVI'  from dual
  8    )
  9  select id,
 10    name,
 11    row_number() over (partition by id order by null) seq
 12  from b;

        ID NAME         SEQ
---------- ----- ----------
         1 TRI            1
         1 TRI            2
         1 TRI            3
         2 ROHIT          1
         2 ROHIT          2
         3 RAVI           1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you still want to store it, now you know how.

Comment: Actually insert needs to be done in table B. When new IDs are inserted in table B, sequentially SEQ are generated.I want to know how to insert in such a way i table B

Answer (score 0):

Don't have multiple sequences. Just use a single sequence in the B table and accept that there will be gaps for each `ID` and then if you need sequential values you can calculate them as needed using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and, if you need to, put it in a view. Also, don't duplicate the name from table `A` in table `B`; keep your data normalised.

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  id   NUMBER(8,0)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT A__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id   NUMBER(8,0)
       CONSTRAINT B__id__nn NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT B__id__fk REFERENCES A(id),
  seq  NUMBER(8,0)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT B__seq__pk PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then you can create your sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO A ( name )
SELECT 'TRI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ROHIT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RAVI' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO B ( id )
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

And:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   B
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | SEQ
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  1 |   2
>  2 |   3
>  3 |   4
>  2 |   5
>  1 |   6
> ```

If you want your output then create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW B_view ( id, name, seq ) AS
SELECT b.id,
       a.name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY seq )
FROM   B
       INNER JOIN A
       ON ( B.id = A.id )
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   b_view
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | NAME  | SEQ
> -: | :---- | --:
>  1 | TRI   |   1
>  1 | TRI   |   2
>  1 | TRI   |   3
>  2 | ROHIT |   1
>  2 | ROHIT |   2
>  3 | RAVI  |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d2325f81b9b5186f7d3fe17a4faec68)*